# Message while app is deleted

Tags: java, android

I want to know why  users delete my app. So, I what to know why users do it. Is it possible to ask the user why they deleted my app? API something like ACRA library.

Comment: You can't actually do it on Android http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803549/995020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It´s not!**

When an Android-APP was uninstalled there is an INTENT coming up.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED

So every other App might be able to recognize your app beeing uninstalled but not your app itself.