# How do I know if my app has been uninstalled or freshly installed?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, installation, listener, uninstallation

Here's the scenario: `Provided the servers and api are already there, so my device is already registered with my account. I want it to call the API unregister() if the app has been uninstalled. The same with Facebook app, if a user is currently logged in then the FB app has been uninstalled, the next time it is installed and run, you will be redirected to the login page and not the timeline. How do they do this? How do I listen the event of my app being uninstalled or freshly installed?`

Basing from what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8803549/1968739) which was 3 years ago, you cannot do that in Android but I'm not sure if it is already possible by this time?

But anyway, I was thinking of using `BroadcastReceiver` but would require to have another app to listen the uninstallation event of my main app.

I've ran out of ideas, if anyone has something in mind. I will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: when user uninstall its app, the cache and all data will be cleared. so facebook app read its localstorage and find nothing, then redirect it to login page

Comment: normally after uninstall the app redirects to the login page! 
In your case how do you manage your user login

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Everytime I open the app, the API checks the mac_address if it is "active" so it will not go to login page. I want to change the status to "deleted" through my API once the app is uninstalled.